# Como definir um intervalo para o rangeslider no plotly?

Tags: r, plotly

Eu possuo um gráfico feito no `dyGraphs` que usa a função `dyRangeSelector`. Nela eu consigo usar o argumento `dateWindow` para definir a janela inicial que meu gráfico apresentará. Ficando dessa forma:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu gostaria de fazer a mesma coisa utilizando a função `rangeslider` do pacote `plotly`. Tentei utilizar o seguinte código:

```
library(quantmod)
library(plotly)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

getSymbols("AAPL")

ggplotly(
      AAPL %>%
            fortify() %>%
            rename(Data = Index,
                   Valor = AAPL.Adjusted) %>%
            ggplot(aes(x = Data, y = Valor)) +
            geom_point(shape = 16, color = "#176180") +
            geom_line(color = "#176180") +
            labs(x = "", y = "") +
            scale_x_date(breaks = "3 months",
                         date_labels = "%m/%y") +
            theme(panel.background   = element_rect(fill = "white", colour = "white"),
                  axis.line          = element_line(colour = "black", linetype = "dashed"),
                  axis.line.x.bottom = element_line(colour = "black"),
                  panel.grid.major   = element_blank(),
                  plot.title         = element_text(size = 12, face = "bold"),
                  panel.grid.minor   = element_blank(),
                  plot.margin = margin(5, 5, 15, 5)),
      width = 700,
      height = 400) %>%
      layout(xaxis = list(rangeslider = list(type = "date"))) %>%
      config(displayModeBar = FALSE)
```

Mas não estou conseguindo limitar o range da função para os últimos 120 dias. Tentei utilizar `rangeslider(start = Sys.Date()-120, end = Sys.Date())`, mas não funcionou. O gráfico sempre sai dessa forma, aparecendo todo o intervalo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]